# Killing a java zombie process

Tags: linux, kill-process, zombie-process

I am running an experimental java application and every time I kill or stop the application, zombie processes get created. I know zombies are not really an issue as they (supposedly) will not consume resources. However, my RAM free space gets significantly less than it should be. Here is the dump of

```
ps aux | grep java

3052  8.5  0.0      0     0 ?        Zl   Sep24 127:24 [java] <defunct>
6644  0.9  0.0      0     0 ?        Zl   Sep24  13:20 [java] <defunct>
8325  0.7  0.0      0     0 ?        Zl   Sep24  11:01 [java] <defunct>
8954  0.7  0.0      0     0 ?        Zl   Sep24  11:01 [java] <defunct>
16229  1.3  0.0      0     0 ?        Zl   Sep24  16:57 [java] <defunct>
19222  106  0.0      0     0 ?        Zl   Sep24 1346:37 [java] <defunct>
```

None of the following works :(

```
kill -9 PID , kill -1 PID, kill -KILL PID
```

I cannot reboot my machine! so I would highly welcome any solutions.

Comment: If your machine won't reboot and the process table is so large that it's taking a significant portion of your RAM, it's time to pull the power plug or call an exorcist.

Comment: You have several fundamental misunderstandings, but the most important is this: The amount of free RAM you should have is as close to zero as is possible. Free RAM is a pure loss. It's not like if you use half your RAM today, you can use extra RAM tomorrow. If you want RAM to be free, take it out of your machine and sit it on your desk. When we want to make a system perform better, we get it to use more RAM, usually by adding RAM.

Comment: Well, thanks David but I know what I am talking about.

Comment: @DotNet: If you did, you wouldn't have said, "my RAM free space gets significantly less than it should be". Free RAM should be as close to zero as the OS can get away with.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The wait(2) man page tells you:

> A child that terminates, but has not been waited for  becomes  a  "zombie".  The kernel maintains a minimal set of information about the zombie process (PID, termination status, resource  usage  information)  in order to allow the parent to later perform a wait to obtain information about the child.  As long as a zombie is not removed  from  the  system via  a wait, it will consume a slot in the kernel process table, and if this table fills, it will not be possible to create further  processes. If a parent process terminates, then its "zombie" children (if any) are adopted by init(8), which automatically performs a wait to  remove  the zombies.

So you have to look for the *parent* process IDs of your zombies and kill these. Then `init` will bury your zombies. For this `ps -f` or `pstree` will help you.

Comment: If the __direct__ parent of your zombies is init, then you have a _real_ problem, because this means your init does not do it's job anymore. That in turn is a very good reason for a reboot and a deep look into the bug databases of your distribution.

Comment: Thanks A.H. I agree with you and I've just rebooted the machine.